# Python if statement syntax?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am working on a BMI calculator and have a bunch of if statements for the "status" part of it. For some reason I am getting an error through Eclipse saying that "Expected:)" but I have no clue what is missing.

Here is a sample of the code which is throwing the error:

```
BMI = mass / (height ** 2)

if(BMI < 18.5):
    status = "Underweight"

if(BMI => UNDERWEIGHT and BMI < NORMAL):
    status = "Normal"

if(BMI => NORMAL & BMI < OVERWEIGHT):
    status = "Overweight"

elif(BMI >= 30):
    status = "Obese"
```

Comment: Where do you see this error

Answer (score 4):

As already noted on other answers, the error is caused by `=>`, and `&` is a [bitwise operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) which is not what you want in this context. But as per @Blckknght's comment, you can probably simplify this anyway by only comparing to the maximum value each time. Also, get rid of the parentheses as these are not needed in Python.

```
BMI = mass / (height ** 2)    
if BMI < UNDERWEIGHT:
    status = "Underweight"
elif BMI < NORMAL:
    status = "Normal"
elif BMI < OVERWEIGHT:
    status = "Overweight"
else:
    status = "Obese"
```

Answer (score 3):

`=>` does not mean anything in Python.  "Greater than or equal to" is instead written `>=`.

Comment: Its worth noting that if you used a `elif` for the second and third `if` statements, and an `else` for the last one, you wouldn't need to do any `>=` tests at all. Another issue is the `&` in the third test.

Answer (score 2):

You might change:

```
if(BMI => NORMAL & BMI < OVERWEIGHT):
```

to:

```
if(BMI >= NORMAL and BMI < OVERWEIGHT):
```

With some of the other suggestions, you might re-write the entire statement as:

```
if BMI < UNDERWEIGHT:
    status = "Underweight"

elif BMI >= UNDERWEIGHT and BMI < NORMAL:
    status = "Normal"

elif BMI >= NORMAL and BMI < OVERWEIGHT:
    status = "Overweight"

elif BMI >= OVERWEIGHT:
    status = "Obese"
```

Comment: you may want to consider getting rid of ( and ) as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
BMI = mass / (height ** 2)

if (BMI < 18.5):
    status = "Underweight"
elif (UNDERWEIGHT < BMI < NORMAL):
    status = "Normal"
elif (NORMAL < BMI < OVERWEIGHT):
    status = "Overweight"
else
    status = "Obese"
```

In python we can check whether a number is in the range, like this

```
if 0 < MyNumber < 2:
```

This will be Truthy only when MyNumber is some number between 0 and 2.

Comment: I think the OP wants <= rather than < in several places